# Using two values to act as a key for one value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, maps

How can you use 2 values to act as a key for one value in Javascript? I'm coding out a ticketing system for a theater client and need to be able to use a day-week combination to lookup an external id for a url.

Each show can run on a given day (monday, tues, wed, etc), but also run during a certain "week of the run" such as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th. So a show might run Tuesday on the 2nd week of the run. And the day AND week are unique, but need to look up the value and choose the appropriate link url. The only part of the url that I need to worry about is the id, which is numeric and each combo would have a link like https://example.com/52, https://example.com/53, https://example.com/54 etc.

So how can I use two values to act like a key for one result? Again, I'm trying to find a way where Day-2 + Week-2 => id-54, or day-4 + week-3 => id-63

Possible options are:

- Nested if statements (messy, unwieldly, and I'd prefer not to do that.)
- An array for each day. So Tuesday (day 2) would have week values such as ['week1', 'week2', 'week3'] And with if statement for each day, I just need to look up the right week. (Better, but could be improved).
- And there has to be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: you can do it with numbers, such as first number will be number of week and second number of day, so for ex. key `40` would be `sunday of 4th week`

Comment: So just use a standard array, where the numerical representation for day 1 and week 3 would be 13, with it's appropriate key value?
like array = ('13' => '56')

Comment: You can use array with index as this number, or use this number as `key` for object, like => `obj[13] = ...whatever`, but be warned, that this number will be automatically converted to string, so it will be ` { '13' : 'whatever' }`

Comment: You probably want an object, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can store data in nested dictionaries for easy-access later on, like this

```
// Initialize days dictionary 
var days= {
             Monday: {},
             Tuesday: {},
             Wednesday: {},
             Thursday: {},
             Friday: {},
             Saturday: {},
             Sunday: {}
          };

// Then store 
days["Tuesday"]["Week-4"] = "id-54";
days["Thursday"]["Week-3"] = "id-63";
```

When you want to access them, simply use

```
days["Thursday"]["Week-3"]
```

for accessing Thursday-Week3 id and so on...

Comment: This could work. I'm using numerical representation for the day and for the week, but the concept is the same. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)